# Perl occur error when use lib

Tags: perl, batch-file, perl-module

I have a weird problem, I `called a CMD batch script, then the batch script called a perl script`

The C# launch process

```
//
// Launch process.
//
string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = fileName,
    Arguments = arguments,
    WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};

Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

The batch script:

```
"%PerlFolder%\perl.exe" "%CodeFolder%\test.pl"
```

the test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

#...
#code
foreach $key (keys(%ENV)) {
    printf("%-10.10s: $ENV{$key}\n", $key);
}
```

but it occurs an error when use the lib, I can't catch the error since it occurs include library(compile) before execute ,it seems like it don't found the lib, so I replace it with absolute path

```
use lib "C:/Program Files (x86)/perl/lib/strict.pm";
```

but it still not work, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is the error? Can you edit the question to add the complete error?

Comment: @zdim, I can't catch the error since it occurs include library(compile) before execute

Comment: @zdim, or do you know how to catch that?

Comment: But how do you know that there is an error?  Does the Perl script even run?  Does it work on its own?   (I don't think you can have a problem with `use strict;` if your Perl installation is good.)

Comment: @zdim, if the perl script execute successfully, it will print the environment variables, it obviously not, but if I remove the  `use strict;`, it print whose variables, so it must occurs error when `use perl lib`

Comment: Ah, I see now.  When you include `use strict;` you must _declare_ all variables.  That's the point of it.  So your `foreach $key ...` needs to be `foreach my $key ...`.  (In Perl you declare variables with `my` keyword.)  So correct that and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149449/discussion-between-alen-lee-and-zdim).